# Can not recognise wifi if the device is far from router

Tags: internet, router

My phone connect when device is close to router but signal is weak.In some routers it connect to wifi and works fine. My mobile data works fine. When i have my mobile data open and activate the hotspot option, other devices recognises the signal but won't connect.
My device it is Samsung S4 and android version is 5.0.1.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about other devices connecting to the internet through the Wi-Fi Hotspot on your phone?

Comment: @CodeMonkey,Yes,right.Other device won't connect through my Wi-Fi Hotspot.Also my device connect to router but signal it is weak.Thanks!